# MSSQL Group By Query - Use Results to perform next query

Tags: php, sql-server

I am not sure if this is possible or not, but I have a table named category.  Each category is assigned to a division.  So I query my db to get a group of the categories

```
SELECT id_category FROM [db].[dbo].[category]
WHERE (id_division = <<id_division_here>>) GROUP BY id_category
```

I get the list of categories I expected.  Now, I need to make sure that these categories exist in another table called content that has a field that holds multiple values - so a LIKE statement works for that...  basically

```
SELECT title FROM [db].[dbo].[content]
WHERE (assigned_to LIKE '% <<id_category_here>> %') ORDER BY title
```

My question is, is there a way for me to combine the two queries or do they need to be done separately?  Can I group the results from one table and use it as the search criteria to query another table?  Thanks for helping me to figure this out. :)

Comment: If id_category uniquely identifies a category record, you shouldn't need to group by id_category in your first query. Also, are you able to amend table structures? Storing multiple id_categories in a single `assigned_to` field violates first normal form and should be normalised, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT a.id_category, o.title 
FROM [db].[dbo].[category] a
JOIN [db].[dbo].[content] o
  ON o.assigned_to LIKE '%'+ a.id_category + '%'
WHERE a.id_division = <<id_division_here>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ c.title, t.id_category 
FROM dbo.content c
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.id_category 
    FROM dbo.category c
    WHERE c.id_division = <id_division_here> 
) t
WHERE c.assigned_to LIKE '%' + t.id_category + '%' 
ORDER BY c.title
```

Comment: this worked perfectly - even if it is years later! :)